# Need the full correct html code for this Table

Tags: web, frontend

[Image table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ0EN.png)

Please write full html codes for this table. You may see the Table image from above via the link.

```
<table border="1" width="800">
<tr>
    <th>Level1</th>
    <th>Level2</th>
    <th>Level2</th>
    <th>Info</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="6">System</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="4">System Apps</td>
    <td rowspan="2">System Memory</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">SystemEnv</td>
    <td rowspan="1">SystemEnv2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Memeory Test</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the table code :

```html
<table border="2">
        <tr>
            <th>Level 1</th>
            <th>Level 2</th>
            <th>Level 3</th>
            <th>info</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowSpan="6">System</td>
            <td rowSpan="4">System apps</td>
            <td rowSpan="3">SystemEnv</td>
            <td>App Text</td>
            <td>foo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>App memory</td>
            <td>foo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>App test</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Systemenv2</td>
            <td>App test</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowSpan="2">System Memory</td>
            <td rowSpan="2">Memory test</td>
            <td>memory func</td>
            <td>foo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Memory Func</td>
            <td>foo</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```